# KDE - Displays only shows monitor or laptop screen, not both

Tags: multiple-monitors, kde

I have a Carbon X1 running Ubuntu 19.04 with KDE Plasma 5. When colleagues also running KDE plug an external monitor in, *System Settings -> Display and Monitor* will show all the displays. Mine however only show one box, even though the *Primary Display* dropdown lists *No Primary Output*, *Laptop Screen* and *U28D590 (HDM1)*. This seems to mean I can mirror my output on both screens, but nothing else.

[image]

How do I get both displays to appear, so I can arrange them, and display different out on each.

Comment: Are your colleagues also running "running Ubuntu 19.04 with KDE Plasma 5" or are they using Kubuntu 19.04?

Comment: Thanks - I'll have to check. Should it matter though? Are you saying Ubuntu 19.04 with KDE Plasma 5 may not support multiple monitors?

Comment: The GUI may be misleading. When the screens are mirrored and have the same resolution, they are stacked on top of each other and you only see the display in front. Try dragging the monitor somewhere else, you should now see your second monitor.

Comment: Brilliant - that's exactly it. Feel free to add it as an answer and I'll accept it (although I'm surprised it is not a dupe)

Comment: Using `@` before "danzel" maybe better: @danzel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When multiple monitors display the same content, have the same resolution and are not unified, they are stacked exactly on top of each other in the GUI. Just drag the monitor in front to the side to reveal the other monitor(s):

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Seems a weird GUI choice to me

Answer (score 1):

I ended up encountering this issue when I disabled some of my monitors to so that I could share my "entire screen" in a video call without it being super wide and tiny for the person on the other side.

I thought there would be some grayed-out monitors in the UI that I could toggle back on, since they way I had toggle them off was by clicking on them.

Turns out you have to select them from the dropdown to re-enable them.

[image]